# Riccati and Benoulli

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Riccati eq

$\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2 + 2xy - 3x^2 + 1$

Let $y*$ denote a special solution when by setting $Y = y - y*$ you can get a Benoulli eq

For this Riccati equation $y* = x$ is a solution

Solve this equation for a general solution by letting $Y = y - x$

My working is this:

Given $Y = y - x => y = Y + x$

so $\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2 + 2xy - 3x^2 + 1$

then sub $y = Y + x$

=> $\frac{d(Y+x)}{dx} = (Y+x)^2 + 2x(Y+x) - 3x^2 + 1$

simplifying gives

=> $\frac{dY}{dx} = Y^2 + 4xY$

let $u = \frac{1}{Y}$ then $\frac{du}{dx} + 4xu = -1 $

Now that is in the form of a linear ODE and that is where the problem kicks in. Solving for u I get $u = \frac{-1}{4}$ but my friend got $u = e^{-4x} - 1$

Her solution works out nicely but mine doesn't and she tried explaining to me  but I didn't get it. Will someone be able to help me?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

> simplifying gives
>   => $\frac{dy}{dx} = Y^2 + 4xY$
>   let $u = \frac{1}{Y}$ then $\frac{du}{dx} + 4u = -1 $

by:

Simplifying gives $\frac{dY}{dx} = Y^2 + 4xY$ (*you wrote $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $\frac{dY}{dx}$*). Let $u = \frac{1}{Y}$ then $\frac{du}{dx} + 4xu = -1$ (*you forgot a factor $x$*).

Then solve the differential equation in $u$.

**Note:**

> Her solution works out nicely

Really? How so?

**Edit:** Solving the differential equation in $u$ and plugging the result in $Y$ then in $y$ yields the general solution of the initial equation as
$$
y(x)=x+y(0)\,\mathrm e^{2x^2}\,\left(1-y(0)\int_0^x\mathrm e^{2t^2}\mathrm dt\right)^{-1},
$$
where the integral may probably be expressed in terms of the error function $\mathrm{erf}$, without any obvious gain.

Comment: I missed this term.

Comment: well for her solution, after getting $u = e^{-4x} - 1$ then since we let $u = \frac{1}{Y}$ so $\frac{1}{Y} = e^{-4x} - 1$ => $Y = 1/e^{-4x} - 1$ and at the beginning we said y = Y + x so then she ends up with $y = x(e^{-4x} + 1)/e^{-4x} - 1$

Comment: And this solves the equation one started with?

Comment: oh...you're right. if we sub that in the ODE I don't think we would get a solution...

Comment: umm so to solve for u do I just treat it as a linear ODE and find an integrating factor? if I do that I get the integrating factor as e^2x...

Comment: I mean I get e^2x^2

Comment: Indeed, one gets $\mathrm e^{-2x^2}$, not $\mathrm e^{\pm4x}$.

Comment: okay so I get $u = e^{-2x^2} + C$ which can also be written
$u = Ae^{-2x^2}$ now what do I do? do I just sub that into Y = 1/u?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you made a mistake when you solved $\frac{du}{dx} + 4u = 0$ the solution of which being $u=c e^{-4 x}$. Then, starting with this, for the solution of $\frac{du}{dx} + 4u = 1$  you must use the method of the variation of the coefficient which will then lead to $u=c e^{-4 x}-\frac{1}{4}$. So, for $c=0$, you are right, for $c=1$, your friend is not right (close to) but, for the general case, I am afraid that none of you is right.

Is this making the problem clearer ?

Comment: a little...so for this question my friend's solution for u should be used in order to find a general solution? or do we need to find another solution? also how did you use the method of variation to get the solution for u? could you show me? thank you for answering though :)

Comment: I suppose that you accept that $u=c e^{-4x}$ when the rhs is zero. Now consider that $c$ is a function of $x$ then $u'=e^{-4 x} c'-4 e^{-4 x} c$ which then leads to $c'=e^{4x}$; so $c=k+\frac{e^{4 x}}{4}$ then $u=?$

Comment: "I suppose that you accept that u=ce−4x" I don't "accept" that, and it is wrong.